# Rails 5 error related to postgres Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5, pg

I am facing socket issue after reinstalling postgres from my pc Ubuntu 20. Every time I create new project, I have to define host in database.yml otherwise it will throw  Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"? error. My pg server is up and running on socket /var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432. What settings I have to do now in pg gem or postgres so that It can initialize the port to var/run.postgresql and not to unix domain sotkcet?

I tried to reinstall pg gem and postgresql but it didnt work. Now my only option left to reinstall every thing if I want to avoid defining host in database.yml.

Comment: How did you actually install Postgres? I installed it in Ubunto via apt-get and it works with zero configuration.

Comment: You can change unix_socket_directories on the server to point to the location where the client expects to find the socket.  On my test servers I usually set it to multiple of them, '/tmp,/var/run/postgresql', to cover both bases.  But what is wrong with just specifying the host?

Comment: "initialize the port to var/run.postgresql and not to unix domain sotkcet"  The var directory is not an alternative to the Unix domain socket, rather it is the location of that socket.  The alternative to Unix domain sockets is to use TCP, such as 'localhost'.

Comment: Your client library is either weird, or was installed in some weird way (self-compiled? statically linked?).  If it were installed with apt-get the usual way, the the client and the server would agree by default on where to look for the socket and you wouldn't need to change anything.

Comment: If I reinstalls the pg gem with gem install pg  --   --with-pg-lib=/usr/lib   , then I will not face this issue any more. The issue is I installed pg gem without any option before reinstalling the whole postgresql.I wasn't facing any issue before reinstalling the postgresql.

Answer (score 0):

I had multiplie versons of postgresql installed, other was installed with anaconda. pg_conf was pointing towards that postgresql and once I uninstalled this version and reinstall rails pg gem, my issue solved.